# Can WER produce dumps similar to .dump /ma

Tags: windbg, windows-error-reporting

My impression is that dumps produced my winDbg

```
.dump /ma
```

contains more than just a full dump

Configuring [WER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains DumpType 0: Custom dump
CustomDumpFlags bitwise combination of  [MINIDUMP_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
But what hex value gives dumps similar dumps as .dump /ma

All the bit combinations are a bit overwhelming for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WinDbg's `.dump /ma` saves the dump with these flags:

```
Flags           41826
                0002 MiniDumpWithFullMemory
                0004 MiniDumpWithHandleData
                0020 MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules
                0800 MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo
                1000 MiniDumpWithThreadInfo
                40000 MiniDumpWithTokenInformation
```

You can verify this by opening the crash dump file in WinDbg and issuing the (undocumented) `.dumpdebug` command.

So you will want to specify 41826 (hex) or 268326 (decimal) in the `CustomDumpFlags` registry key.